# A basic question on Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I take the union of all the open intervals removed in the process of construction of Cantor set and then take the closure of that set. What is that set ? I think it is just the rational points who are the boundary of the removed open intervals. Is it correct ?

What about in the case where we consider only the open intervals removed in odd stages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the whole interval [0,1]. Take $c\in C$. For any $\epsilon>0$, the interval $(c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$ containts points of $[0,1]\backslash C$ (why?), so  $c$ is in the closure of $[0,1]\backslash C$.